# iPhone failing to upload contacts to iCloud

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, data-synchronization, contacts

For some reason, contacts are just not syncing between my iPhone and Mac. When I add  new contacts on my phone, they don't appear on iCloud. If they do, I might start troubleshooting the Mac.

I made sure that contacts is turned on under 'iCloud' on my phone. Low power mode is off. I'm currently connected to Wi-Fi. This has been going on for months unfortunately, and my contacts have never synced.

I'm on iOS 13 and macOS Catalina.

Comment: Is the contact in iCloud.com? If so, just wait for the second device to sync, if not, you should troubleshoot the first one.

Comment: Huh, that's a really good point. I just checked and the new contacts are not synced on icloud.com. Not really sure what to do about that though, since contact syncing is turned on in the settings on my phone.

Comment: Low power mode is off. I'm currently connected to Wi-Fi. This has been going on for months unfortunately, and my contacts have never synced.

Comment: Add a contact on icloud.com and see if it appears on iphone..

Comment: Just tried it. Strangely, yes the contact appears on my phone.

Comment: So did the ones you added on iPhone go up ? And by extension on Mac ? you might want to post a self answer if all's good now.

Comment: No unfortunately they're still not there